# ember-cli-mirage trying to stub auth0 (external) URL

Tags: ember.js, auth0, ember-simple-auth, ember-cli-mirage

I am working on a new Ember.js project and using ember-cli-mirage to stub out my requests. The project is going to use `ember-simple-auth` and Auth0 for user authentication. I began implementing them in my project, but I'm getting a weird error in the console when I try to sign up with my Google account using the Auth0 login modal:

```
Your Ember app tried to GET 'https://(my auth0 domain).auth0.com/userinfo',
but there was no route defined to handle this request.
Define a route that matches this path in your
mirage/config.js file. Did you forget to add your namespace?
```

(my auth0 domain redacted above)

I have no idea why Mirage would be trying to stub out a request to an external URL. I was reading the Mirage docs and tried using `this.passthrough()` in my `mirage/config.js` file so Mirage would make a real request, but that seems to have had no effect (I'm guessing it only explicitly applies to routes within a `namespace` defined in the config file).

Can anyone help me understand why this is happening and how to stop Mirage from doing it? Thank you!

Comment: @Selman Sorry, not sure if the review response came off as harsh (it was one of the pre-set options) - why do you suggest removing the `ember-cli-mirage` tag?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ember CLI Mirage intercepts *all* ajax (`XMLHttpRequest`) and `fetch` requests by default. You have to whitelist the requests that should be passed through by using `server.passthrough()` method. (`this` is `server` instance in `mirage/config.js`.) You could use relative and absolute URLs with `server.passthrough` as well as with all route handlers. So `server.passthrough('https://(my auth0 domain).auth0.com/userinfo')` should fix your issue.

Comment: That did it! Thank you so much @jelhan ! I didn't realize Mirage mocks ALL requests, good to know.